# How to see request payload in jclouds?

Tags: jclouds

I'm trying to connect to an OpenStack system using jclouds and get the following error:

```
org.jclouds.rest.AuthorizationException: POST https://foo.bar.org:5000/v3/auth/tokens HTTP/1.1 -> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
  at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.handlers.NovaErrorHandler.handleError(NovaErrorHandler.java:93)
```

(This happens when I run `val region = conn.getConfiguredRegions.iterator.next`)

Is there a way for me to see the request payload to the POST request to help in diagnosing the issue further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `jclouds.headers=DEBUG` and `jclouds.wire=DEBUG` should reveal the request.

Comment: Check this guide too: https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/logging. You will also have to configure the following property to see the auth payloads; otherwise jcloids hide them as they may contain sentitive info: https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/javadoc/2.1.x/org/jclouds/Constants.html#PROPERTY_LOGGER_WIRE_LOG_SENSITIVE_INFO

Comment: @IgnasiBarrera Thanks! - I wasn't quite able to get logging to work; I added another question related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455763/how-to-minimally-get-log-info-working-with-slf4j-in-jclouds